# How to find the index of element in two dimensional hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, indexing, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array containing names and dates:

```
name_date_array = [[John Doe, 8/9/14], [Jane Smith, 9/4/14], [Mary Jane, 6/5/14],
[John Doe, 5/2/14]]
```

(I am rewriting this as it was unclear) I have two variables: `patient_name` and`collection_date`. I am trying to find the index of the sub-array containing `patient_name` and a date that is smaller than 'collection_date'. Here is what I have from falsetru:

```
patient_name = browser.find_element(:xpath => ".//*[@id='dialog-modal-cancel-hl7-preview']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]").text

collected_date = browser.find_element(:xpath => ".//*[@id='dialog-modal-cancel-hl7-preview']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]").text
mo, da, yr = collected_date.split('/').map(&:to_i)
cd = [yr, mo, da]

name_admit_array.index { |name, date|
    m, d, y = date.split('/').map(&:to_i)
    dt = [y, m, d]
    name == patient_name and (dt <=> cd)<0
}
```

This works great, but the reason I am rewriting this (other than to save face as it was terribly written before) is that I have another question. `collection_date` is the date that a lab sample was collected for a particular client (`patient_name`). Each sub-array contains a patient's name, and their admission date. A patient can have several entries with the same name but different admission dates if they were a patient more than once.

I need to find the index of the sub-array that contains `paitient_name` and contains the admission date associated with the `collection_date`. This means that sub-array indexed needs to have the patient's name and the admission date that is before the collected date, but also closest to the collected date if there are more than one entries with admission dates before the collection date. I hope that makes sense.

For example, if the collection date is 9/3/14 I need to return the index of the sub-array `[John Doe, 8/9/14]` not `[John Doe, 5/2/14]` because the first contains the admission date associated with that collection (the stay during which the lab was collected from him). Clearly just requiring that the `collection_date` is larger than the admission date, `dt`, is not enough.

Comment: You gave two criteria for the inner "dimension." What is the criterion for the outer "dimension"?

Comment: By your use of plural in "I want to find the index of entries," you imply that you are looking for possibly more than one entry (sub-array). But you wrote you want the return to be a single object `0`. What happens when there is more than one match?

Comment: You wrote that the criteria are given as `patient_name` and `admission_date`. What happened to that, and why is `==John Doe & >8/9/14` used?

Comment: Only one entry should return, so my use of "entries" was wrong, sorry about that. And when I put ==John Doe & >8/9/14 I was referring to what patient_name and admission_date will be equal to. As I said this is my first attempt at programming, and I am still learning line by line.

Comment: You have an accepted answer.  To ask a new question, you should ask a new question instead of editing the current question.  You can copy or reference material from here in your new question.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I will do that. Still learning here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-index) with a block. It will return the index of hte first item for which the block returns `true`:

```
name_date_array = [
  ['John Doe', '8/9/14'],
  ['Jane Smith', '9/4/14'],
  ['Mary Jane', '6/5/14'],
  ['John Doe', '5/2/14']
]

name_date_array.index { |name, date|
  m, d, y = date.split('/').map(&:to_i)
  dt = [y, m, d]
  name == 'John Doe' and (dt <=> [14, 8, 9]) < 0
}
# => 3
```

If you want get multiple indexes ([`Enumerable#each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index), [`Enumerable#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)):

```
name_date_array.each_with_index.select { |(name, date), i|
  m, d, y = date.split('/').map(&:to_i)
  dt = [y, m, d]
  name == 'John Doe' and (dt <=> [14, 8, 9]) < 0
}.map { |x, i| i }
# => [3]
```

Comment: A variant of #2: `name_date_array.size.times.select do |i| name, sdate = name_date_array[i]; name == 'John Doe' && (sdate.split('/').rotate(-1).map(&:to_i) <=> [14, 8, 9]) < 0; end # => [3]`.

Comment: Thank you for that, I don't know why I couldn't find this elsewhere, but it seems to work! You're the best!